# Jquery counter in a for loop

Tags: jquery, counter

I am trying to make a counter in jquery something like this...

```
for(counter = 1;counter<4;counter++){
}
```

would this work?

Well I am just saying the loop as a test...what I am ultimately trying to do is remove duplicate images from this code...

```
            // Preloads images within a rel group
            if (settings.preloading) {
                preload = [
                    getIndex(-1),
                    getIndex(1)
                ];
                while (i = $related[preload.pop()]) {
                    src = $.data(i, colorbox).href || i.href;
                    if ($.isFunction(src)) {
                        src = src.call(i);
                    }
                    if (isImage(src)) {
                        img = new Image();
                        img.src = src;
                    }

                }
```

Comment: That's just javascript and it will work. You don't need jquery for that.

Comment: Code doesn't bite - try it yourself!

Comment: "var counter = 1". and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490590/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: Another question to ask is what are you trying to do? If you are using jQuery, is there a reason you need to loop, or can you just select all the items and apply the [style, animation, etc] to all of them without looping?

Comment: It will run. Did you try it? You haven't really told us what you are trying to do or why. How is jQuery related here?

Comment: To do what? Your `for` loop will work as a `for` loop, but I have no idea what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, I would do

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) {
```

to be more explicit.